¿Por qué al actualizar un registro en CRUD Laravel 11 me da error "El método Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection::update no existe"
Estoy realizando un CRUD en Laravel 11, los métodos para crear, leer y eliminar funcionan sin problemas, pero al intentar actualizar un registro al procesar el formulario me arroja el error: "Method Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection::update does not exist."
En web.php tengo las siguientes rutas para el CRUD:
//routs maintenance
Route::middleware('auth')->group(function () {
    Route::post('/dashboard/academic_grade/store', [Academic_gradeController::class,'store'])
        ->name('academic_grade.store'); //creación de grado académico

    Route::put('/dashboard/academic_grade/update/{academic_grade}', [Academic_gradeController::class, 'update'])
    ->name('academic_grade.update'); //actualización de grado académico

    Route::delete('/dashboard/academic_grade/destroy/{academic_grade}', [Academic_gradeController::class, 'destroy'])
    ->name('academic_grade.destroy'); //eliminación de grado académico

    Route::get('/dashboard/academic_grade/list', [Academic_gradeController::class, 'index'])
        ->name('academic_grade.index'); //listado de grados académicos

    Route::get('/dashboard/academic_grade/create', [Academic_gradeController::class, 'create'])
        ->name('academic_grade.create'); //formulario de creación de grado académico

    Route::get('/dashboard/academic_grade/{academic_grade}/edit', [Academic_gradeController::class, 'edit'])
        ->name('academic_grade.edit'); //formulario de edición de grado académico

    Route::get('/dashboard/academic_grade/{academic_grade}/show', [Academic_gradeController::class,'show'])
        ->name('academic_grade.show'); //formulario de visualización de grado académico

});

En el controlador Academic_gradeController.php para el método update tengo el siguiente código:
    public function update(Request $request, Academic_grade $academic_grade)
    {

        $academic_grade = Academic_grade::find($academic_grade);
        $academic_grade->update(
            [
                'name'=> $request->input('name'),
                'state' => $request->input('state'),
           ]
        );

        return redirect('dashboard/academic_grade/list');
    }

La vista edit.blade.php tiene el siguiente código:
<x-app-layout>
    <x-slot name="header">
        <h2 class="font-semibold text-xl leading-tight">
            {{ __('Grados académicos') }}
        </h2>
    </x-slot>
    <div class="space-y-6">
        <div class="p-4 sm:p-8 bg-white shadow sm:rounded-lg dark:bg-gray-800">
            <div class="max-w-xl">
                @foreach ($academic_grade as $grade)
                <header>
                    <h2 class="text-lg font-medium">
                        {{ __('Edita el grado académico') }} <b>Id: ({{$grade->id}})</b>
                    </h2>

                    <p class="mt-1 text-sm text-gray-600 dark:text-gray-400">
                        {{ __('Aquí puedes modificar o desactivar el grado académico.') }}
                    </p>
                </header>
                <form action="{{ route('academic_grade.update', $grade->id) }}" method="POST" class="mt-6 space-y-6">
                    @csrf
                    @method('PUT')
                    <div class="space-y-2">
                        <x-form.label for="name" :value="__('Nombre')" />
                        <x-form.input id="name" name="name" type="text" class="block w-full" value="{{ $grade->name }}" 
                            required />
                    </div>
                    <div class="space-y-2">
                        <input class="px-4 py-2 border-gray-400 rounded-md focus:border-gray-400 focus:ring
                        focus:ring-purple-500 focus:ring-offset-2 focus:ring-offset-white dark:border-gray-600 dark:bg-dark-eval-1
                        dark:text-gray-300 dark:focus:ring-offset-dark-eval-1 block" type="checkbox" name="state" 
                        @if ($grade->state == 'active')   
                            checked='checked'
                            value="active"
                        @endif
                        >
                        <x-form.label
                            for="state"
                            :value="__('Activo')"
                        />
                        <x-form.error :messages="$errors->updatePassword->get('name')" />
                    </div>
                    <div class="flex items-center gap-4">
                        <x-button>
                            {{ __('Guardar') }}
                        </x-button>

                        @if (session('status') === 'password-updated')
                            <p x-data="{ show: true }" x-show="show" x-transition x-init="setTimeout(() => show = false, 2000)"
                                class="text-sm text-gray-600 dark:text-gray-400">
                                {{ __('Saved.') }}
                            </p>
                        @endif
                    </div>
                </form>
                @endforeach
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</x-app-layout>

La tabla academic_grades tiene los siguientes campos:


$academic_grade es una colección, y no puedes usar update en una colección. Intenta agregándole first, por ejemplo: $academic_grade = Academic_grade::find($academic_grade)->first();. Conviene revisar si tu tabla tiene bien definida la llave primaria o bien el valor que estás pasando en parámetro, el cual taaaambién se llama $academic_grade
. Y evita una reutilización confusa de las variables, no te cobran por definir una variable nueva.

@A.Cedano Muchas gracias, resolvió el problema que tenía, y seguí tu consejo sobre las variables.
